# Typescript: Exporting Enum classes to JS produces compilation error

Tags: javascript, typescript, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I trying to export Kotlin Enum classes to JS

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalJsExport::class)
@JsExport
enum class interEnum {
    SAMPLE
}
```

But in Angular Project, after importing as NPM module, the respective TS block in `module_name.d.ts`  throws error during compilation when trying to run.

```
abstract class interEnum { // exported from Kotlin/JS 
    private constructor();
    static get SAMPLE(): com.example.demoapp.interEnum & {
        get name(): "SAMPLE";
        get ordinal(): 0;
    };
    static values(): Array<com.example.demoapp.interEnum>;
    static valueOf(value: string): com.example.demoapp.interEnum;
    get name(): "SAMPLE";
    get ordinal(): 0;
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Error from ng serve:**

```
ERROR in demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:286:13 - error TS1131: Property or signature expected.

286             get name(): "SAMPLE";
                ~~~
demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:289:9 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

289         static values(): Array<com.example.demoapp.interEnum>;
            ~~~~~~
demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:289:24 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

289         static values(): Array<com.example.demoapp.interEnum>;
                           ~
demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:289:62 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

289         static values(): Array<com.example.demoapp.interEnum>;
                                                                 ~
demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:290:9 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

290         static valueOf(value: string): com.example.demoapp.interEnum;
            ~~~~~~
demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:290:29 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

290         static valueOf(value: string): com.example.demoapp.interEnum;
                                ~
demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:290:38 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

290         static valueOf(value: string): com.example.demoapp.interEnum;
                                         ~
demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:291:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

291         get name(): "SAMPLE";
                ~~~~
demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:291:19 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

291         get name(): "SAMPLE";
                      ~
demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:292:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

292         get ordinal(): 0;
                ~~~~~~~
demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:292:22 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

292         get ordinal(): 0;
                         ~
demo_app/demo_app.d.ts:294:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

294 }
```

---

What are these errors ? Since I am new to JS and TS, I can't understand this. The editor not showing any errors.

If I remove the `get` keywords, then it's compiling successfully.

I can't understand what's wrong here. Please help me

Comment: Please post your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @EvgeniDikerman Added now !

Comment: try `skipLibCheck`

Comment: @EvgeniDikerman. Sorry. Not working . added "skipLibCheck": true in tsconfig.json inside compilerOptions. Not working !

Comment: The output doesn't seem to be correct TypeScript code. Missing constructor body, missing implementations for `static` methods, etc.

Comment: Which Kotlin version are you using? As of Kotlin 1.6.10, enums are not exportable - support was added with 1.6.20. https://dev.to/touchlab/jsexport-guide-for-exposing-kotlin-to-js-20l9

Comment: @majusebetter . I am using 1.7.10

Comment: @RagAnt Ok, but the output is not correct TypeScript code. You could give the tips in the link above a try.

Comment: @majusebetter . In that link, they mentioned enums export support was added since 1.6.20. So why I need that suggested object workaround.

Comment: @majusebetter Is it a bug within Kotlin/JS Engine if he output is not correct TypeScript code?

Comment: @RagAnt Seems like the support for exporting enums has not been added, yet (1.7). Under "It is currently prohibited to export the following kinds of declarations" they list enum classes. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-js-export/

Comment: @majusebetter Oh my god. Yes. Still they not yet added them . Okay . I will use the suggested workaround on the link. Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official [documentation for 1.7](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-js-export/), it is prohibited to export enum classes.

This [link](https://dev.to/touchlab/jsexport-guide-for-exposing-kotlin-to-js-20l9) provides some useful tips for exposing enums to TypeScript.

Comment: Oh my god. Yes. Still they not yet added them . Okay . I will use the suggested workaround on the link. Thanks for your time !

Comment: There is no error shown such as "non-exportable type", so I thought that they added them now !

Comment: Yes, the article was misleading. Good luck!